# Can't install qt5-default on Ubuntu 22.04 - required to install IQmol

Tags: dependencies, 22.04, default, qt5

Installing IQmol is relatively easy (I did it with ubuntu 20.04 without problems). However with Ubuntu 22.04 there is a problem with the qt5-default package that seems to have been updated for this new LTS version of Ubuntu.

In the manual it says the following, after downloading iqmol_2.14.deb from their website:
"*`#> sudo dpkg -i iqmol_x.x.x.x.deb` `#> sudo apt-get install -f`
The second command is required to resolve the dependency on the Qt libraries, which
you may not have installed.*"

From the first command the error is as follows:
"*dpkg: dependency issues prevent iqmol configuration:
iqmol depends on qt5-default; however:
**The qt5-default package is not installed.**
dpkg: error processing iqmol package (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Errors encountered while processing
iqmol*"

And from the second:
"***The following packages will be REMOVED:
iqmol**
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/N]*"

I have searched, unsuccessfully, for a way to install qt5-default manually on Ubuntu 22.04, but I still don't see how.
Please, someone who can point out the step-by-step.
Thank you very much in advance.

Edited:

I found that IQmol can be successfully installed using Wine and the Windows installer. FYI.

Comment: Those instructions are old. There's a better way now: Dowload the deb and use `sudo apt install /path/to/the/iqmol_x.x.x.x.deb` . That will automatically resolve dependencies *if they are resolvable*. Your errors suggest that the IQmol developer have not tested with 22.04 yet, so those dependencies might not be resolvable in 22.04 yet.

Comment: Thank you, @user535733, but this came out:

"_[...] The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 iqmol : Depends: qt5-default but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages._"

As you said, most likely the IQmol developers have not tested with this Ubuntu version, yet.
Still, I find it very odd that one cannot install in 22.04 the old version: _qt5-default_.

Comment: I think you have three options: You can stay on the 22.04+deb path by trying to haywire an older version of `qt5-default` to install, or you can revert to 20.04, or you can build from source for 22.04.

Comment: Exactly, thank you.
Could you give me an idea of how to haywire or build from source... I would like to stay on 22.04... but if not, then I will have no choice but to go back to 20.04.

Comment: Haywiring: You try to install older packages into your 22.04 system. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. You get the packages from http://packages.ubuntu.com. Building from source: The instructions are on the IQmol download page. Advice: If an attempt fails, remember to completely clean up before starting again. The biggest blocker to many installs is detritus left over from previous failed attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting, unsuccessfully, for a while for the Ubuntu 22.04 repositories to allow installing the old version of qt5-default, I got the idea to install IQmol for Windows (iqmol.exe) via Wine.

Indeed that was the best option and solution to my problem. I totally recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

Download `qt5-default_5.99.99+fake-13ubuntu37_all.deb` package from the official repository [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/qt5-default/download) then

```
sudo dpkg -i qt5-default_5.99.99+fake-13ubuntu37_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i iqmol_2.14.deb
```

All done!

Works for `Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64`